# Context free language false proof

Tags: computer-science

What is wrong with the following proof?

Show whether $L$ is context-free or not, where $L = \left\{ a^nb^{2n}a^n | n \geq 0\right\}$

We know $\left\{a^nb^n | n \geq 0 \right\} $ and $\left\{b^na^n | n \geq 0 \right\} $ are context-free.

Notice that, $\left\{a^nb^n \right\} $$\left\{b^na^n \right\} = \left\{ a^nb^{2n}a^n\right\}$

Since CFL's are closed under concatenation we can conclude that $L$ is also context-free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ab$ is in the concatenation language but not in $L$; do you see why?

For a correct argument I suggest using the pumping lemma for context-free languages.

Comment: Are you saying that those n's are independent of each other in the two languages that are concatenated?

Comment: @Pure: Yes, they are.